Compute inverse of a special 2 by 2 block matrix.
Let
$$X\in\mathbb{R}^p,\quad
\tilde{X} =  (1, X^{\top})^{\top}\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1},\quad \tilde{\Sigma}=\mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^{\top}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{(p+1)\times (p+1)}
$$
$$
(\tilde{\Sigma})^{-1}=\left(\mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^{\top}\right]\right)^{-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{(p+1)\times (p+1)}, \quad \tilde\mu = (1, \mathbb{E} [X^{\top}])^{\top}\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1}
$$
Claim: $\tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \tilde{\mu}=e_1\equiv (1,0,...,0)^{\top}$. Writing it more explicitly, I want to show
$$
\left(\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mathbb{E}[X^{\top}] \\
\mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[XX^{\top}]
\end{array}\right] \right)^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \boldsymbol{0}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Material I think is relevant: consider
$$
R=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}\right]
$$
Assume $A$ is nonsingular; then the matrix $R$ is invertible if and only if the Schur complement $D-C A^{-1} B$ of $A$ is invertible, and
$$
R^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}+A^{-1} B\left(D-C A^{-1} B\right)^{-1} C A^{-1} & -A^{-1} B\left(D-C A^{-1} B\right)^{-1} \\
-\left(D-C A^{-1} B\right)^{-1} C A^{-1} & \left(D-C A^{-1} B\right)^{-1}
\end{array}\right] .
$$
In my problem, $A=1, B =\mathbb{E}[X^{\top}], C=\mathbb{E}[X], D=\mathbb{E}[XX^{\top}] $

Therefore I have been trying to compute $(\tilde{\Sigma})^{-1}$. Mentioned in the quoted material, one important component is the Schur complement:
$$
(D -CA^{-1}B)^{-1} = \left(\mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{X} \tilde{X}^{\top}\right] - \mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{X}\right]\mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{X}^{\top}\right]\right)^{-1}
$$
But I don't know how to continue to proof my claim. Once I know how to expression this in terms of known matrices without the inverse sign, I can continue compute $(\tilde{\Sigma})^{-1}$, and multiply it by $\tilde\mu$, and see if it is equal to $e_1$.

Your proof is much easier than you're making it. If we take both sides of the equation
$$
\left(\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mathbb{E}[X^{\top}] \\
\mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[XX^{\top}]
\end{array}\right] \right)^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \boldsymbol{0}
\end{array}\right]
$$
and multiply by
$\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 
1 & \Bbb E[X^\top]\\ \Bbb E[X] & \Bbb E[XX^\top]
\end{smallmatrix} \right]$
on both sides, then we see that the equation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mathbb{E}[X^{\top}] \\
\mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[XX^{\top}]
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
 1 \\
 \boldsymbol{0}
\end{array}\right]
$$
is equivalent. This equation, however, can be quickly verified using block-matrix multiplication or using the fact that  the product $A\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\\mathbf 0\end{smallmatrix} \right]$ yields the first column of $A$.

Thank you for pointing out this observation! I think I pay to much attention on solving that inverse block matrix.
